fastlane plugin for AppGallery corrupting APK
I have been having an issue with uploading our app to AppGallery for the last week or 2. When the app gets uploaded to AppGallery using the Fastlane plugin fastlane-plugin-huawei_appgallery_connect
my APK becomes corrupt and will not be processed(infinitely processes and times out) on AppGallery, I suspect it is the Plugin causing the issue because if I build the app manually and upload it, It works fine and gets processed
also, the corrupted APK does not function correctly if tested using the Cloud debugger
This started happening after I removed google-services from the build flavor, It was previously uploading fine
I've been in contact with Huawei support regarding the issue but it's a slow process and they don't seem 100% sure either. I've also reported this issue on the repo of the plugin and did get a response from another user having the same issue which validates my suspicion more
The code itself is 100% and I've tested the app extensively on the Huawei Cloud debugger which works
I am very much at a loss

This was due to the Fastlane Huawei appGallery plugin using an outdated version of the API interface This was resolved by the Plugin manager

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
